# How do I apply both bold and italics in python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm working on making a dictionary. I'm using  python-docx to put it into MS Word. I can easily make it bold, or italics, but can't seem to figure out how to do both. Here's the basics:

```
import docx

word = 'Dictionary'

doc = docx.Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph()
p.add_run(word).bold = True

doc.save('test.docx')
```

I have tried p.add_run(word).bold.italic = True, but receive a 'NoneType' error, which I understand.

I have also tried p.bold = True and p.italic = True before and after the add_run, but lose formatting all together.

Word's find/replace is a simple solution, but I'd prefer to do it in the code if I can.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `add_run` method will return a new instance of `Run` each time it is called. You need create a single instance and then apply `italic` and `bold`

```
import docx

word = 'Dictionary'

doc = docx.Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph()

runner = p.add_run(word)
runner.bold = True
runner.italic = True

doc.save('test.docx')
```

Comment: Excellent, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!