# How i do make this paragraph bold using docx in python

Tags: python, python-docx

I need to make this paragraph bold but I am not able to do so
I used p.bold = True but it did not work
I also used add_run for each line but it is showing that int type and bool type do not have any attribute add_run.

```
    p = document.add_paragraph(F"""





{doj}

Employee Code: {record[57]}

{record[1]} {record[2]} {record[3]} {record[4]}
{record[12]},
{record[13]},{record[15]}

Dear {record[2]},""")
```

I tried to do it like this but it did not work

```
    document = Document()

    p = document.add_paragraph(F"""
{doj}""").bold = True
    p.add_run(F"""Employee Code: {record[57]}""").bold = True
    p.add_run(F"""{record[1]} {record[2]} {record[3]} {record[4]}""").bold = True
    p.add_run(F"""{record[12]},""").bold = True
    p.add_run(F"""{record[13]},{record[15]}""").bold = True

    p.add_run(F"""Dear {record[2]},""").bold = True
```

Comment: What python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hope This will Solve your issue 
[How do I apply both bold and italics in python-docx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709527/how-do-i-apply-both-bold-and-italics-in-python-docx)

Explanation provided at https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

```
Run objects have both a .bold and .italic property that allows you to set their value for a run:

paragraph = document.add_paragraph('Lorem ipsum ')
run = paragraph.add_run('dolor')
run.bold = True
paragraph.add_run(' sit amet.')

which produces text that looks like this: ‘Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.’

Note that you can set bold or italic right on the result of .add_run() if you don’t need it for anything else:

paragraph.add_run('dolor').bold = True

# is equivalent to:

run = paragraph.add_run('dolor')
run.bold = True

# except you don't have a reference to `run` afterward

It’s not necessary to provide text to the .add_paragraph() method. This can make your code simpler if you’re building the paragraph up from runs anyway:

paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.add_run('Lorem ipsum ')
paragraph.add_run('dolor').bold = True
paragraph.add_run(' sit amet.')
```

Comment: It seems like OP uses the .bold syntax correctly. I dont see how this answer solves the issue

Comment: i was suppose to add it as a comment .-.